# Finding the roots of a 4th degree polynomial function in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm trying to find a method to find the roots of the following 4th degree polynomial equation in Tensorflow:

```
k1 = 339.749
k2 = -31.988
k3 = 48.275
k4 = -7.201


r = k1 * x + k2 * x**2 + k3 * x**3 + k4 * x**4
```

where `r` is a given tensor and I need to find the roots for every element of `r`. Specifically I'd need a tensor, in which every element is the real part of the solution with the smallest real part in the equation defined by the corresponding element of tensor `r`.

Since there is a formula for the 4th degree polynomial equation, I'm hoping that there exists a computationally efficient solution to this problem that I couldn't find.

Comment: you could use a method for finding roots, called Halley's method, and so find it is possible to find the roots using **`tensorflow.gradients`** like this `r = k1 + k2 * x + k2 * x **2 + k3 * x**3 + a4 * x**4` and use **r** as argument to [`gradients()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) maybe in tensor data type format or any `[x, y]` compatible data parameter.

Comment: "I am trying" well what have you tried? Where are you stuck? This is not a code-writing/problem-solving service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use newton-raphson method to find the roots of any equation, as long as it is a continuous equation. First, randomly choose a starting point (this point must not be a point where the gradient of your function is zero), and then you can calculate a second approximation using,

```
x_new = x - f(x)/f_prime(x)
```

where `f(x)` computes your equation, and `f_prime(x)` computes the gradient of your equation at the point `x`.

You can build `f_prime(x)` using `tensorflow.GradientTape()`

Here is a full working example,

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Your equation
def f(x):
    k1 = 339.749
    k2 = -31.988
    k3 = 48.275
    k4 = -7.201

    r = k1 * x + k2 * x**2 + k3 * x**3 + k4 * x**4
    return r

# Function to calculate the gradient of your equation at point x
def f_prime(x):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y = f(x)
    dy_dx = tape.gradient(y, x)
    m = dy_dx.numpy()
    return m

# Function to find second approximation to x
def update(x):
    x_new = x - f(x)/f_prime(x)
    return tf.Variable(x_new)

x = tf.Variable(2, dtype='float32') # Randomly choose a starting point
epochs = 100 # Number of iterations

for i in range(epochs):
    x = update(x)

print(x.numpy())
```

The calculated root will be the closest root to the starting point you've chosen. Try a different number, like 200, and you will get a different result.

You can set a greater epoch number to get a more accurate solution. If you don't get a point at which f(x)=0, this is because your starting point was very far away from the solution, so you need to set a greater epoch number

Play around with different functions and different starting points to get a better understanding of newton-raphson method to find solutions to continuous equations. If you face problems understanding this method, [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/newton-raphson-method/) might be helpful.